# Tomcat 8.5: Header missing in the HTTP response

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8.5

Using tomcat8.5 ...I'm not getting the complete response as using tomcat8.0.

There is a difference between this 2 versions about the HTTP 
request or response?

---

PUT tomcat8.0 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 08:59:48 GMT
```

---

PUT tomcat8.5 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200                                
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 09:05:20 GMT
```

I'm using C++ soket methods to send the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 8.5 dropped support for the reason phrase. See the [migration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html):

> ## HTTP connector changes
>
> HTTP reason phrases have been removed by default, but can be re-enabled using the
>   sendReasonPhrase configuration attribute.

You can reenable it in your [Connector configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes), but it'll be gone in Tomcat 9.

`<Connector ... sendReasonPhrase="true">
 ...
</Connector>`

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously there's a difference in the content of the actual response. However, the `Server:` header means nothing as far as `HTTP 1.1` is concerned, and it carries no special meaning in the protocol.

Technically, the two responses are identical, and carry identical information about the response: this is a chunked-encoded response. End of story.

If you're writing a client that uses HTTP, you should be familiar with [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), which explains this.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm trying to find out why this difference in response though. For tomcat8.0: `GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 994` and for tomcat8.5: `GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 992` in tomcat logs. Can this be a clue for what is happening ?

Comment: When I runt the client I have the same for both versions: `PUT /printing/pc HTTP/1.1" 200 14`

Comment: The server is free to return any response that complies with HTTP 1.1. Both responses do. An HTTP client doesn't care. Since the Server: header is meaningless, it does not, and should not care. It is not specified in the protocol. A client that has a problem if the header does or does not exist is broken, and should be fixed to comply with RFC 2616.